# "NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type" every time i make an exicutable

Tags: python, windows, exe, pyinstaller

i am trying to make an executable but I keep "getting the NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader."
here is the example from the command promp after trying to run the program

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 331, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 50, in main
  File "lib\site-packages\pygame\pkgdata.py", line 50, in getResource
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1141, in resource_exists
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1440, in has_resource
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1495, in _has
NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type
slidepuzzle returned -1
```

code

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *
print('make shure to stretch regularly while playing')

pygame.init()



BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 50)
smallFont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)        

FPS = 60 #frames per second setting
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

#set up window
screenwidth=500
screenhight=500
Screensize=pygame.display.set_mode((screenwidth,screenhight),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption('Hyper-active')

Black = (0,0,0)
White = (255,255,255)
Red = (255,0,0)
Green = (0,255,0) 
Blue = (0,0,255)

colorList=[Black,White,Red,Green,Blue] 

win_for_good = 0

shipx= 250
shipy= 250

columb=10   
rows=10

lifecount=1

TileWidth=screenwidth/columb
TileHight=screenhight/rows  

ship = pygame.image.load('shipsprite1.png')
shipHitBox= pygame.draw.rect(Screensize,Black,(shipx, shipy, 38, 45))

def makeText(text, color, bgcolor, top, left):
    # create the Surface and Rec5t objects for some text.
    textSurf = BASICFONT.render(text, True, color, bgcolor)
    textRect = textSurf.get_rect()
    textRect.topleft = (top, left)
    return (textSurf, textRect)

def makeSmallText(text, color, bgcolor, top, left):
    # create the Surface and Rec5t objects for some text.
    textSurf = smallFont.render(text, True, color, bgcolor)
    textRect = textSurf.get_rect()
    textRect.topleft = (top, left)
    return (textSurf, textRect)



def winPlace (x1,y1,x2,y2):
    WinLocation=pygame.draw.rect(Screensize, Red,(x1,y1,x2,y2))


def checkForCollision (objectLocation,tileList):
    if objectLocation in tileList:
        return True
    else:
        return False 

def generateTiles (maxrows, maxcols,numberoftiles,excludedTiles):
    tileList=[]
    tileList.extend(excludedTiles)
    #removes starting location so you dont crash into your starting location
    tileList.remove(getshiplocationOutput)
    count=0
    while count < numberoftiles:
        row=random.randint(0,maxrows)
        col=random.randint(0,maxcols)
        x1=TileWidth*col
        y1=TileHight*row

        if (x1,y1) == (9,9):
            print('hit win zone')
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(Screensize,White,(x1,y1,TileWidth,TileHight),0)
            count+=1
            tileList.append((row,col))

        if (row,col) in tileList:
            joe=0

        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(Screensize,White,(x1,y1,TileWidth,TileHight),0)
            count+=1
            tileList.append((row,col))

    return tileList

def lives (lifeCount):
    textSurf, textRect = makeSmallText('rounds till win: {0}'.format(lifeCount), Black, White,0,50)
    Screensize.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def getshiplocation (x,y,w,h):
    col=int(x/w) 
    row=int(y/h)
    print('x =',col,'y =',row)
    return (row,col) 
loop= True

Screensize.fill(Black)
Screensize.blit(ship, (shipx,shipy))
getshiplocationOutput=getshiplocation(shipx,shipy,screenwidth/columb,screenhight/rows)
currantTileList=generateTiles(columb,rows,20,[getshiplocationOutput])
winPlace(450,450,500,500)
lives(lifecount)
gameWin=False     
gameOver=False 
pygame.draw.rect(Screensize,(255,242,0),shipHitBox,2)


while loop:

    if getshiplocationOutput == (9,9):
        print('good job')
        gameWin=True


    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key ==(K_LEFT):
                ship=pygame.image.load('shipsprite4.png')
                shipx-=30
                getshiplocationOutput=getshiplocation(shipx,shipy,screenwidth/columb,screenhight/rows)
                gameOver=checkForCollision(getshiplocationOutput,currantTileList)
                Screensize.fill(Black)
                getshiplocationOutput=getshiplocation(shipx,shipy,screenwidth/columb,screenhight/rows)
                currantTileList=generateTiles(columb,rows,20,[getshiplocationOutput])
                winPlace(450,450,500,500)
                pygame.draw.rect(Screensize,(255,242,0),shipHitBox,2)
                lives(lifecount)   

            elif event.key ==(K_RIGHT):
                ship=pygame.image.load('shipsprite2.png')
                shipx+=30
                getshiplocationOutput=getshiplocation(shipx,shipy,screenwidth/columb,screenhight/rows)
                gameOver=checkForCollision(getshiplocationOutput,currantTileList)
                Screensize.fill(Black)
                currantTileList=generateTiles(columb,rows,20,[getshiplocationOutput])
                winPlace(450,450,500,500)
                pygame.draw.rect(Screensize,(255,242,0),shipHitBox,2)
                lives(lifecount)

            elif event.key ==(K_UP):
                ship=pygame.image.load('shipsprite1.png')
                shipy-=30
                getshiplocationOutput=getshiplocation(shipx,shipy,screenwidth/columb,screenhight/rows)
                gameOver=checkForCollision(getshiplocationOutput,currantTileList)
                Screensize.fill(Black)
                currantTileList=generateTiles(columb,rows,20,[getshiplocationOutput])
                winPlace(450,450,500,500)
                pygame.draw.rect(Screensize,(255,242,0),shipHitBox,2)
                lives(lifecount)

            elif event.key ==(K_DOWN):
                ship=pygame.image.load('shipsprite3.png')
                shipy+=30
                getshiplocationOutput=getshiplocation(shipx,shipy,screenwidth/columb,screenhight/rows)
                gameOver=checkForCollision(getshiplocationOutput,currantTileList)
                Screensize.fill(Black)
                currantTileList=generateTiles(columb,rows,20,[getshiplocationOutput])
                winPlace(450,450,500,500)
                pygame.draw.rect(Screensize,(255,242,0),shipHitBox,2)
                lives(lifecount)

            elif event.key == (K_r):
                ship=pygame.image.load('shipsprite1.png')
                shipx= 250
                shipy= 250
                Screensize.fill(Black)
                Screensize.blit(ship, (shipx,shipy))
                getshiplocationOutput=getshiplocation(shipx,shipy,screenwidth/columb,screenhight/rows)
                currantTileList=generateTiles(columb,rows,20,[getshiplocationOutput])
                winPlace(450,450,500,500) 
                pygame.draw.rect(Screensize,(255,242,0),shipHitBox,2)
                lives(lifecount)
                print('reset')

            elif event.key == (K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()                



    Screensize.blit(ship, (shipx,shipy))

    if gameOver == True:
        print('point of death',getshiplocationOutput)               
        pygame.time.wait(1000)
        shipx= 250
        shipy= 250
        Screensize.fill(Black)
        Screensize.blit(ship, (shipx,shipy))
        getshiplocationOutput=getshiplocation(shipx,shipy,screenwidth/columb,screenhight/rows)
        currantTileList=generateTiles(columb,rows,20,[getshiplocationOutput])
        winPlace(450,450,500,500)
        gameOver=False
        shipx= 250
        shipy= 250
        win_for_good-=1
        lifecount+=1
        lives(lifecount)

    if gameWin == True:
        loop=False
        Screensize.fill(Black)
        win_for_good+=1
        lifecount-=1
        ship=pygame.image.load('shipsprite1.png')
        shipx= 250
        shipy= 250
        Screensize.fill(Black)
        Screensize.blit(ship, (shipx,shipy))
        getshiplocationOutput=getshiplocation(shipx,shipy,screenwidth/columb,screenhight/rows)
        currantTileList=generateTiles(columb,rows,20,[getshiplocationOutput])
        winPlace(450,450,500,500)
        lives(lifecount)
        gameWin=False      
        pygame.draw.rect(Screensize,(255,242,0),shipHitBox,2)

    if win_for_good==1:
        Screensize.fill(White)
        textSurf, textRect = makeText('SUPURB!', Black, White,120,245)
        Screensize.blit(textSurf, textRect)
        loop=False
        pygame.display.quit
    else:
        loop=True

    if win_for_good==-5:
        Screensize.fill(Black)
        textSurf, textRect = makeText('GAME OVER', Red, Black,110,245)
        Screensize.blit(textSurf, textRect) 
        ship=pygame.image.load('shipsprite1.png')
        pygame.time.wait(1000)
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
        loop=False
    else:
        loop=True


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()


    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)


print('end of the program')
```

this is the full code please help.

Comment: please post your code in addition to the error.

Comment: which converter do you use